# Flask flask.cli.NoAppException with app factory

Tags: python, flask, config

I'm attemping to split up my configuration settings into different classes within a config.py file, as documented [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#development-production)

I've split my project up into folders like so:

```
/bloggy
    autoapp.py
    config.py
    /app
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
        /static
        /templates
```

My `config.py` looks as follows

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'secret key'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'db.sqlite3')


class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True


config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'testing': TestingConfig,
    'default': DevelopmentConfig
}
```

I have an application factory file `autoapp.py`  to create my Flask application from the desired environment variable

```
import os
from app import create_app
app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
```

My `app/__init__.py` looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

After running

`$ export FLASK_APP=autoapp.py`

and

`$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1`

and starting the server with:

`$ flask run`

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jwe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 178, in __call__
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "/home/jwe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 166, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/jwe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/jwe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 155, in _load_app
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/jwe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 170, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/jwe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 231, in load_app
    rv = locate_app(self.app_import_path)
  File "/home/jwe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 95, in locate_app
    'is .py' % module)
flask.cli.NoAppException: The file/path provided (autoapp) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

Is there anyway I can get my application to use the settings laid out in `config.py` or should I take a different approach?

Comment: I ran into the same error, but I had an unnecessary `__init__.py` at the root level. Make sure you don't have that in `/bloggy`. You are in `/bloggy` when you `flask run`?

Comment: I gave up and decided to drop the application factory and just keep everything inside __init__.py instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding the name of the flask application will help. Like following:

```
app.config.from_object(bloggy.config[config_name])
```

See [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#configuring-from-files) in flask doc.